# Capturing values of variables across dataframes from a dict of dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have 3 dataframes in a dict where the key is a month identifier and value is the dataframe:

[image]

Below is a snapshot of the dataframes along with the keys:

[image]

Now, for each unique variable I want to capture it's correlation strength across all the months/dataframes.
If a variable has correlation values in a df then that should be captured or else the value would be 0. Something like VLOOKUP in excel.

The final dataframe would look like below:

[image]

This seems very complicated to me to implement in python so can someone please help me with this?

Below is the code to generate the sample data and create the dict of dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'Variable_Name':'Pending_Disconnect','correlation': 0.553395448},
                    {'Variable_Name':'status_Active','correlation': 0.539464806},
                    {'Variable_Name':'days_active','correlation':0.414774231},
                    {'Variable_Name':'days_pend_disco','correlation':0.392915837},
                    {'Variable_Name':'prop_tenure','correlation':0.074321692},
                    {'Variable_Name':'abs_change_3m','correlation':0.062267386}
                    ])


df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'Variable_Name':'Pending_Change','correlation': 0.043461995},
                    {'Variable_Name':'status_Active','correlation': 0.038057697},
                    {'Variable_Name':'ethnic','correlation':0.037503202},
                    {'Variable_Name':'days_active','correlation':0.037227245},
                    {'Variable_Name':'archetype_grp','correlation':0.035761434},
                    {'Variable_Name':'age_nan','correlation':0.035761434}
                    ])


df3 = pd.DataFrame([{'Variable_Name':'active_frq_N','correlation':0.025697016},
                    {'Variable_Name':'active_frq_Y','correlation': 0.025697016},
                    {'Variable_Name':'ethnic','correlation':0.025195149},
                    {'Variable_Name':'ecgroup','correlation':0.023192408},
                    {'Variable_Name':'age','correlation':0.023121305},
                    {'Variable_Name':'archetype_nan','correlation':0.023121305}
                    ])

dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
months = ['Jan - Feb 2018','Jan - Mar 2018','Jan - Apr 2018']

sample_dict = dict(zip(months,dfs))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can replace the column name of your dataframe and then use `pd.concat` to concatenate the dataframes.

```
for key, df in sample_dict.items():
    df.rename(columns={'correlation':'correlation '+ key}, inplace=True)
pd.concat(dfs)
```

EDIT: you can also omit the dictionary and do this from the list of dataframes.

```
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df.rename(columns={'correlation':'correlation '+ months[i]}, inplace=True)
pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Hello @onno.. This throws the below error:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @ShuvayanDas `.iteritems()` was a Python 2.x thing and removed in 3.x... use `.items()` instead

Comment: woops, I was running in my Python 2 env. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.concat` as:

```
df1.set_index('Variable_Name',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('Variable_Name',inplace=True)
df3.set_index('Variable_Name',inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1, sort=False).fillna(0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Variable_Name','Jan - Feb 2018','Jan - Mar 2018','Jan - Apr 2018']

print(df)
         Variable_Name  Jan - Feb 2018  Jan - Mar 2018  Jan - Apr 2018
0   Pending_Disconnect        0.553395        0.000000        0.000000
1        status_Active        0.539465        0.038058        0.000000
2          days_active        0.414774        0.037227        0.000000
3      days_pend_disco        0.392916        0.000000        0.000000
4          prop_tenure        0.074322        0.000000        0.000000
5        abs_change_3m        0.062267        0.000000        0.000000
6       Pending_Change        0.000000        0.043462        0.000000
7               ethnic        0.000000        0.037503        0.025195
8        archetype_grp        0.000000        0.035761        0.000000
9              age_nan        0.000000        0.035761        0.000000
10        active_frq_N        0.000000        0.000000        0.025697
11        active_frq_Y        0.000000        0.000000        0.025697
12             ecgroup        0.000000        0.000000        0.023192
13                 age        0.000000        0.000000        0.023121
14       archetype_nan        0.000000        0.000000        0.023121
```

Answer (score 0):

My final code is a combination of codes from @onno & @Sandeep Kadapa:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, df in sample_dict.items():
        df = sample_dict[key]
        df = df.iloc[:,0:2]
        df.rename(columns={'correlation':'correlation '+ key}, inplace=True)
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df,df],axis = 1,sort = False).fillna(0)
```

Thanks a lot for the quick reverts.